# How to estimate passengers destinations from flightradar data?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, fitting, graph-theory

We have a graph with vertices corresponding to airports and edges corresponding to flights between those airports. On edge between airports A and B we have and number of passengers transferred from A to B and from B to A for a given timeframe (selected and fixed for the rest of the discussion as a day\week for simplicity). Sometimes there is no direct flight between airports A and B so people have to fly via connection, say A->C->D...->B.

How can we estimate number of people starting in a given airport A and having their destination another given airport B? It is easy in case of direct flight, but harder if there is a connection.

I cannot think of anything besides simple markov model. Fit markovian transition matrix (with exit\enter states separate for each airport) to observed data and calculate corresponding probabilities. This seems as too simplistic and will probably have a high variance.

Comment: I guess the main problem with the Markov model is that it's unlikely that someone will take an absurd number of flights to get to a particular location, since there's likely a shorter sequence of flights to accomplish the same goal. Also, people won't take silly routes like A -> B -> A -> C. So in that sense, it's not a Markov process, since the decision to take a flight or exit the airport depends on the sequence of previous flights.

Comment: Are the flows balanced? If not, you're kind of out of luck because the system isn't closed; people arrive and leave at each airport, and your data doesn't seem to track the inflows/outflows from each airport (i.e. people who start/end their trip at airports).

Comment: To follow up, I'm wondering what your precise question is. Is it `given that N people start at airport A, what proportion of people of those N do we expect to end up at airport B?"

Comment: @KevinLi it is a question about real destinations, because I want to study how passenger flows will change if new airport is added or old airport is removed. It is more like `given that N people start at airport A, what proportion of people of those N do we expect to exit at airport B?"

Comment: Ah, then its a problem that you don't track the people that enter/exit at each airport no?

Comment: Yes, we only have inflow-outflow numbers. The data is highly granular, so it is possible to see true destinations: if there are two routes A->C->B and A->D->B and D is temporary unavailable (or, more costly) part of the traffic to from A to B will go through C. Although distinguishing it from noise will be a hard problem itself.

Comment: why would it have a high variance?

Comment: @XiaoxiongLin It was actually a wrong assumption. The problem is process not Markovian as noted by Sycorax in first comment.

Comment: It could be Markovian, but of high order. Are you provided with data of the paths passengers took? Or in the worst case, you could take the order of your Markov process to be the length of the longest path in this graph.

Comment: @KevinLi  Could you elaborate? I have only capacities of planes, no individual tracks. Assuming near full utilization of capacity I can estimate number of people moving from airport A to airport B by direct flights, but I have nothing besides it.

Comment: @Moonwalker Well I understood that comment as "not being strictly first-order Markov process". you can make a second-order / nth-order Markov chain, where transition depends on a tensor not matrix, $T_{tn(destination), tn-1, tn-2, ...}$.

Comment: and of course the more orders you have the more precise your prediction is, but you may have overfitting and may need more samples. Also, depending on the time scale, I don't think coming back to the same airport is that impossible, I have done that a couple of times myself. If it is not that salient, you might as well forget about the difference it makes to transition probability. No model can capture everything and you need good reason to add complexity to the model.

Comment: by different time scale I mean: apparently A->B->A->C is absurd if there's no on-ground time between flights, i.e. the flights happens fast enough in, say, 12 hours. But if they happen in 1-2 days, it has good reason, if happen in 5 days, it makes sense for most people. You can essentially chunk time into 12hr-48hr units, and the slow dynamics will be perfectly first-order Markov. More specifically, the larger time units you take, the more first-order property it exhibits.

Comment: even in the "absurd" case, I think people will do it sometimes for cheaper flights. Some agency will also sell it to different people but appears to you as one person taking absurd connected flights. In both cases, numbers of people are the same. Therefore more generally, I think as long as you don't try to predict individual behavior but the number of people (i.e. treating different people the same and thus you can mathematically combine two people's flights as one person's seemingly "absurd" flight, or vice versa), this second-order constraint has little to zero effect on the thing you care.